# Staying in Brazil as a tourist directly after working visa expires

Tags: working-visas, brazil, polish-citizens

I'm Polish, working in Brazil. I live here on working visa issued for 2 years (VITEM V). After my 2 years end I would like to stay in the country for 2-3 months more, just travelling around, not working at all.

Normally as a tourist I would be able to stay here for 90 days in every 180 days period (prolongable in some special cases).

I understand that when my visa expires I have to leave Brazil. But if I come back e.g. a day later, can I stay for full 90 days as a tourist? Or do I need to leave Brazil for some longer period (90 days?) and only then come back?